# Proof of divergence of a series 4

Tags: divergent-series

Let $ (a_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a **decreasing** sequence of **positive** real numbers. We suppose that there exists a $b>0$ such that $a_k \geq \frac{b}{k}$ for **infinite** values of $k$ . Prove that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ is **divergent**.

Can anybody help me with this calculus exercise? Thanks in advance!

Comment: compare to the harmonic series $\sum \frac1n$

Comment: Agree, but the problem is that the inequality holds for infinite values of $k$, not for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ .

Comment: Right, that's where "decreasing" comes into play.

Comment: We can "choose" the subsequence $ (a_{n_k})$ which satisfies the inequality $a_{n_k} \geq \frac{b}{n_k} , \forall k \in \mathbb{N} $ and use the monotonicity: $n_k \geq k \Rightarrow a_{n_k} \leq a_k $ , for all $k \in\mathbb{N}$. So, $\frac{b}{n_k} \leq a_{n_k} \leq a_k , \forall k \in\mathbb{N} $ . But, can we assume that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{b}{n_k}$ diverges?

Comment: Yeah, that's where I get stuck.

Comment: I think I got it, please check my answer below and let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose $k_1$ such that $a_{k_1}\geq\frac{b}{k_1}$.  Then $\sum_{j=1}^{k_1}a_j\geq k_1a_{k_1}\geq b$.
Now for $i\geq1$ choose $k_{i+1}$ such that $a_{k_{i+1}}\geq\frac{b}{k_{i+1}}$ and $k_{i+1}\geq\frac{i+1}{i}k_i$.  You can do this because there are infinitely many $k$ satisfying the condition.  Then $\sum_{j=k_i+1}^{k_{i+1}}a_j\geq(k_{i+1}-k_i)a_{k_{i+1}}\geq(k_{i+1}-k_i)\frac{b}{k_{i+1}}\geq\frac{b}{i+1}$.
Thus we have rewritten the sum $\sum a_k$ as a sum $\sum c_i$ where each $c_i\geq\frac{b}{i+1}$.  Thus $\sum c_i$ diverges.  Thus $\sum a_k$ diverges.

Comment: Very good approach. But why $(k_{i+1} - k_i ) \frac{b}{k_{i+1}} \geq \frac{b}{i+1} $ ? From the inequality $k_{i+1} \geq \frac{i+1}{i} k_i $ we have that $ \frac{1}{i+1} \geq \frac{k_i}{i k_{i+1}} $.

Comment: $(k_{i+1}-k_i)\frac{b}{k_{i+1}}\geq\frac{b}{i+1}$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $(i+1)(k_{i+1}-k_i)\geq k_{k+1}$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $ik_{i+1}+k_{i+1}-(i+1)k_i\geq k_{i+1}$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $ik_{i+1}\geq(i+1)k_i$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $k_{i+1}\geq\frac{i+1}{i}k_i$.  That proves it.

Comment: You're welcome, it was an interesting exercise, harder than it seemed at first glance.